# Banach fixed point theorem, $T: D \to V, f \to Tf$

Tags: calculus, solution-verification, banach-spaces, fixed-point-theorems

I am working on a problem, but i am not sure if my solutions are correct.

To the Problem:

Let $ (V,‖·‖)    =    (C([0,1]),‖·‖∞)$ be a normalized vector space.
and let $D:=\{f∈V; \| f \| \leq 1/3\}$

We define T :

$T:D→V$ ,  $f→Tf$  ,  $(Tf)(x) =∫_0^x\frac {s^2}{2}+f(s)^2ds$ $(x∈[0,1]).$

**(a)** Show that for all $f_1$ and $f_2$:
$$‖Tf_1−Tf_2‖≤\frac {2}{3}·‖f_1−f_2‖.$$

**for (a) i have** :

$$T' = Tf' = \frac{x^2}{2}+f(x)^2 $$ and then $$0 < Tf'(0) < Tf'(1) = \frac{11}{18} \le \frac{2}{3}$$

After that i am gonna show with mean value theorem it satisfies :
$$‖Tf_1−Tf_2‖≤\frac {2}{3}·‖f_1−f_2‖$$

Is my solution for (b) acceptable? If no, how could i improve my solution?

Comment: For c, just differentiate $h=Th$

Comment: Is the $13$ supposed to be $1/3$?

Comment: Also, I don't think what you did in b really makes any sense. You should just argue directly that $\int_0^x |f(s)^2-g(s)^2| \, ds \leq C \| f-g \|_\infty$ where $C$ is allowed to depend on $\| f \|_\infty,\| g \|_\infty$ (since you're really only interested in $f,g \in D$ anyway) but not on $x$.

Comment: @Ian, I do not see any 13s but if you saw one it has ti be 1/3. I would appreciate it if you write 1/3 instead of 13 for me :).

Comment: OP, in the future, do not use Unicode characters for things that $\mathrm{\LaTeX}$ already has a macro for, like $\Vert$. It’s much easier to type `\lVert` and `\rVert` than to copy and paste the Unicode character every time you need it.

Comment: Yes, having examined the source, the $13$ problem I mentioned was caused by what shoteyes said (you copied $1/3$ and some information was destroyed).